When sending values from SharePlex to Kafka and then back to Oracle, how should the sink connector be configured?
When changes from Oracle are sent to Kafka through SharePlex and the values are as follows, without primary keys. When attempting to send these values back from Kafka to Oracle, how should the JDBC Sink Connector be configured?
topic name: sp_test
The following values are the output from the topic.
{"meta":{"op":"schema","table":""},"schema":{"name":"SPLEX.KAFKA","utcOffset":"9:00","NAME":{"jsonType":"string","num":1,"key":1,"nullable":1,"length":30,"precision":0,"scale":0,"src_name":"NAME"},"ADDRESS":{"jsonType":"string","num":2,"key":1,"nullable":1,"length":60,"precision":0,"scale":0,"src_name":"ADDRESS"},"PHONE":{"jsonType":"string","num":3,"key":1,"nullable":1,"length":12,"precision":0,"scale":0,"src_name":"PHONE"}}}

{"meta":{"op":"del","table":"SPLEX.KAFKA"},"data":{"NAME":"111","ADDRESS":"222","PHONE":"333"}}

{"meta":{"op":"del","table":"SPLEX.KAFKA"},"data":{"NAME":"444","ADDRESS":"444","PHONE":"444"}}

{"meta":{"op":"del","table":"SPLEX.KAFKA"},"data":{"NAME":"aaa","ADDRESS":"aaa","PHONE":"aaa"}}

{"meta":{"op":"del","table":"SPLEX.KAFKA"},"data":{"NAME":"bbb","ADDRESS":"bbb","PHONE":"bbb"}}

{"meta":{"op":"del","table":"SPLEX.KAFKA"},"data":{"NAME":"eee","ADDRESS":"eee","PHONE":"eee"}}

{"meta":{"op":"del","table":"SPLEX.KAFKA"},"data":{"NAME":"ttt","ADDRESS":"ttt","PHONE":"ttt"}}

{"meta":{"op":"del","table":"SPLEX.KAFKA"},"data":{"NAME":null,"ADDRESS":"ccc","PHONE":"ccc"}}

{"meta":{"op":"del","table":"SPLEX.KAFKA"},"data":{"NAME":"zzz","ADDRESS":"zzz","PHONE":"zzz"}}

{"meta":{"op":"del","table":"SPLEX.KAFKA"},"data":{"NAME":"123","ADDRESS":"123","PHONE":"123"}}

{"meta":{"op":"ins","table":"SPLEX.KAFKA"},"data":{"NAME":"aaa","ADDRESS":"aaa","PHONE":"aaa"}}

{"meta":{"op":"commit","table":""}}


The following is the JDBC sink connector configuration that I attempted.
{
    "name": "oracle_jdbc_sink_customers_00",
    "config": {
        "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "sp_test",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521/host",
        "connection.user": "splex",
        "connection.password": "splex",

        "insert.mode": "insert",

        "table.name.format": "KAFKA_JSON_SINK",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "pk.mode": "none",
        "delete.enabled": "none",

        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
    }
}

result
{
"error_code": 500,
"message": null
}

Did you set SUPPLEMENTAL logging on database level? This should store information about all column values in redologs. Also why don't you replicate from Oracle into Oracle directly? Why do you have Kafka in between?
